# Очистные и очистительные: одно и то же или нет?

Tags: значение-слов

О системе очистки воды чаще говорят "очистные сооружения", но при этом может быть "очистительный фильтр". Взаимозаменяемые ли это слова или у них разные оттенки смысла?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слова "очистной" и "очистительный" являются синонимами в значении "предназначенный для очистки".  Слово "очистной" образовано от слова "очистка", слово "очистительный" - от слова "очиститель". Когда какое слово употреблять, думаю, зависит от сложившихся традиций. Сооружения обычно очистные, клизма - очистительная.

Но у слова "очистительный" есть еще значение искупительный, приносящий нравственное очищение. Очистительная  жертва, молитва.